# How to add a 'Send Message To' button on contact page?

Tags: forms, select, contacts

I'm trying to add a "Send Message To" button on a contact form but I'm having trouble with the javascript/PHP. I'm using code I edited that came with the start bootstrap modern business theme, so far I have just added the `$to = '$department'`, set the select tag ID as department and the value of option tags to the appropriate emails.

Not sure if any of that is correct.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 mb-4">
      <h3>Send us a Message</h3>
      <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
        <div class="control-group form-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <label>Full Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
            <p class="help-block"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group form-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <label>Email Address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group form-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <label>Message</label>
            <textarea rows="10" cols="100" class="form-control" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your message" maxlength="999" style="resize:none"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group form-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <label>Send Message To</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="department">
            <option value="sales@website.com">Sales</option>
            <option value="support@website.com">Support</option>
            </select>
            <p class="help-block"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="success"></div>
        <!-- For success/fail messages -->
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-CMD" id="sendMessageButton">Send Message</button>
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])      ||
   empty($_POST['email'])     ||
   empty($_POST['message'])   ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
   echo "No arguments Provided!";
   return false;
   }

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['department']));

// Create the email and send the message
$to = '$department';
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@website.com\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";   
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;         
?>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {

  $("#contactForm input,#contactForm textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
    preventSubmit: true,
    submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
      // additional error messages or events
    },
    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
      event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
      // get values from FORM
      var name = $("input#name").val();
      var email = $("input#email").val();
      var message = $("textarea#message").val();
      var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
      // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
      if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
        firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
      }
      $this = $("#sendMessageButton");
      $this.prop("disabled", true); // Disable submit button until AJAX call is complete to prevent duplicate messages
      $.ajax({
        url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          name: name,
          email: email,
          message: message
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function() {
          // Success message
          $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
          $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
            .append("</button>");
          $('#success > .alert-success')
            .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
          $('#success > .alert-success')
            .append('</div>');
          //clear all fields
          $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
        },
        error: function() {
          // Fail message
          $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
          $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
            .append("</button>");
          $('#success > .alert-danger').append($("<strong>").text("Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!"));
          $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
          //clear all fields
          $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
        },
        complete: function() {
          setTimeout(function() {
            $this.prop("disabled", false); // Re-enable submit button when AJAX call is complete
          }, 1000);
        }
      });
    },
    filter: function() {
      return $(this).is(":visible");
    },
  });

  $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab("show");
  });
});

/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
  $('#success').html('');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not quite sure about your questions, but if you're just trying to get the item from the department form, and send it to that email address, this is the code for that.

**JS:**

```
     data: {
     name: name,
     email: email,
     message: message,
     department: document.getElementById('department').value
     },
```

You must pass the value of the form to the PHP script. You originally had the $message var set to the message and then the next line would set that variable to the department. You need to keep them separate.

```
$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));
$department = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['department']));

// Create the email and send the message
$to = $department;
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@website.com\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";   
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;         
?>
```

Hope this works!